# Not getting any output nor any error for the following code?

Tags: python-2.7, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

i used the following code to scrape data from url(mentioned in the code). I ran the code but its not giving any output nor throwing any error? i am new to python language, it might be a silly problem. Can someone help me?

```
import csv
import urllib2
import sys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.t-mobile.de/smartphones/0,22727,23392-_3-0--0-all-,00.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.prettify()
with open('TMO_DE_2012-12-26.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    spamwriter.writerow(["Date","Month","Day of Week","Device Name","Price"])
    items = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "top"},text=True)
    prices = soup.findAll('strong', {"class": "preis-block"})
    for item, price in zip(items, prices):
        textcontent = u' '.join(price.stripped_strings)
        print unicode(item.string).encode('utf8').strip()
        if textcontent:            
            spamwriter.writerow([time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),time.strftime("%B"),time.strftime("%A") ,unicode(item.string).encode('utf8').strip(),textcontent])
```

Comment: BTW, `soup.prettify()` is meant for outputting readable HTML, but you don't use that output. As used, the line doesn't *do* anything.

Comment: No i did not created any duplicate account, user1915050 is my friend and he is working with me on same project.

Comment: Okidoki; the coding style was somewhat familiar. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no `<div class="top">` elements *with text* on that page, so `items` is an empty list. Remove the `text=True` filter:

```
items = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "top"})
```

and extract all text from it:

```
item_text = u' '.join(item.stripped_strings)
if textcontent and item_text:            
    spamwriter.writerow([time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),time.strftime("%B"),time.strftime("%A") , item_text, textcontent])
```

or, integrated into your existing code:

```
with open('TMO_DE_2012-12-26.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    spamwriter.writerow(["Date","Month","Day of Week","Device Name","Price"])
    items = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "top"})
    prices = soup.findAll('strong', {"class": "preis-block"})
    for item, price in zip(items, prices):
        textcontent = u' '.join(price.stripped_strings)
        item_text = u' '.join(item.stripped_strings)
        if item_text and textcontent:            
            spamwriter.writerow([time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),time.strftime("%B"),time.strftime("%A"), item_text.encode('utf8'),textcontent.encode('utf8')])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I ran the code after making the changes but "items" is showing none for all the rows!

Comment: @ChandanKumar: I tested the code with your URL beforehand. Are you certain you made the correct changes?